# Best practices refreshing access tokens in a MVC Core App containing both views and resources, using Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have been reading up (and watching videos) on how to best implement access and refresh tokens when using a MVC Core application with a lot of ajax call in it. I think I got it right but just wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this. I will edit this post so It can serve as a reference for anyone looking for this information.

My setup:
I have a MVC Core application with a lot of JavaScript. The JavaScripts are using ajax calls to retrieve json or call actions.

Since I don't want my users to be able to access my api using cookie authentication, I'm using app.Map to split my application in two parts. One where the users can access Views using the identity token and one that will require a access token. I'm also adding a cookie to hold the time when I need to refresh my access token.

Startup.cs (I removed the parts that's not importent)

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
  });

  JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

  var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
  {
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "Cookies",

    Authority = LoginServerUrl,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ClientId = "MyApp",
    ClientSecret = "*****",
    ResponseType = "code id_token",
    SaveTokens = true,
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
      OnTicketReceived = async notification =>
      {
        notification.Response.Cookies.Append("NextAccessTokenRefresh", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).ToString());
        notification.Response.Cookies.Delete("AccessToken");
      },
    },

    TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
      NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
      RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
    },
  };

  oidcOptions.Scope.Clear();
  oidcOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
  oidcOptions.Scope.Add("roles");
  oidcOptions.Scope.Add("offline_access");

  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);

  app.Map("/api", (context) =>
  {
    var bearerTokenOptions = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
    {
      AuthenticationScheme = "Bearer",
      Authority = LoginServerUrl,,
      RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
      ScopeName = "MyApi",
      AutomaticAuthenticate = true
    };

    context.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(bearerTokenOptions);
    context.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
  });
```

All ajax calls to controller actions are done using the following url /api/[Controller]/[Action].

I do not want my api to be accessible using the identity token so I also add Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer") attribute to the controller action. So now my controller actions that are getting called by javascript looks like this:

```
[HttpPost, Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
public async Task<JsonResult> DoStuff()
{
}
```

When a javascript needs to access a api resource, the controler first retrives the access token and injects it into the javascript using a custom javascript init method.

This C# method is responsible for refreshing and retriving the access cookie.

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
  var accessToken = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["AccessToken"];
  var nextAccessTokenRefresh = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["NextAccessTokenRefresh"];
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextAccessTokenRefresh) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) || DateTime.Parse(nextAccessTokenRefresh) <= DateTime.Now)
  {
    var refreshToken = await _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token");
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(_appSettings.LoginServerUrl + "/connect/token", _appSettings.LoginClientId, _appSettings.LoginClientSecret);
    var response = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken);
    accessToken = response.AccessToken;

    //Set cookies for next refresh
    _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("NextAccessTokenRefresh", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).ToString());
    _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("AccessToken", response.AccessToken);
  }

  return accessToken;
}
```

On all my $.ajax I have added the following parameter:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken); }
```

Thats it. The default access token expiration is one hour. I always refresh it after half that time.

Now to my questions:

1. Can I improve my code in any way ?
2. Do you see any security related risks doing it this way ?
3. Can I retrieve the access token in the OnTicketReceived ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review; code reviews are off-topic. You need to ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know it's a bit off topic, but ALOT of people using ID4 is looking for this information. I see the same questions popping up on many different forums so I thought I'd make a post here to answer them all. I could have made a blog post, but devs are searching for information here. Shouldn't SO be a place where you find this kind of information ?

Comment: Then you should try to phrase it another way so you are 1) not asking for a code review, 2) not asking for best practices (which is usually just 'primarily opinion-based').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I improve my code in any way ?

Your `Startup.cs` should be something like this(because `Map` works for only '/api' path. For more info see https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html#run-map-and-use):

```
app.MapWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder=>
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(options);
    ...
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
    ....
});

app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder=>
{
    var bearerTokenOptions = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
    {
      AuthenticationScheme = "Bearer",
      Authority = LoginServerUrl,,
      RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
      ScopeName = "MyApi",
      AutomaticAuthenticate = true
    };

    context.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(bearerTokenOptions);
    context.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
});
```

Second point, your cookie expire time is 60 minutes, in this case your refresh token's lifetime will be 60 minutes. I think this may be a problem.

> Do you see any security related risks doing it this way ?

I haven't got enough experience for using refresh tokens, so i can't say that your implementation is secure or not. But i think refresh token(for your implementation) increases complexity also security risks(this is just my opinion and i am not a security expert). I would use only long lived access token with implicit flow(because of simplicity).

> Can I retrieve the access token in the OnTicketReceived ?

Yes, you can:

```
OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
{
     var token = ctx.Ticket.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your excellent answers. I will change the map paths to be more specific and also store the tokens in cookies in the OnTicketReceived. This saves a round trip to the server.

Comment: I was thinking about using a long lived access token, but I'm hoping I can make it safer by refreshing the tokens when ever needed without user interaction. It's a bit more complicated but since I'm only storing the "client secret" on my server, I think it should be fine using refresh tokens.

Comment: Using long lived access token is just my preference(i can't say that use it). I avoid complexity as far as possible and in my opinion complexity is a security risk.

Comment: Lack of complexity in this case is the security risk.  Using long lived tokens allows for XSS attacks.  Short lived tokens with a server side refresh request however, keeps the refresh token secure (on the server) and allows for your authenticated users to continue on the site.  Stealing a token becomes much less of a risk.